# Drupal 7: Programmatically get the list of tags (taxonomy)

Tags: drupal, tags, drupal-7, taxonomy

I need to programmatically create a list of the tags used in a Drupal 7 website. I'm browsing through the api/functions, but can't find something like "get_list_of_terms()" :-)

How should I proceed?
Thanks!
J.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Exactly.  A slightly more complete example is (you can substitute with your own vocabulary vid):

```
if ($terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vocabulary->vid)) {
  foreach ($terms as $term) {
      // Do something with $term->tid or $term->name
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's of great help :)

Answer (score 5):

To get a list of taxonomy terms for a particular vocabulary, you could use [`taxonomy_get_tree`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_tree/7)